# Android compose dialog screen , status bar color change to black show line between dialog and statusbar

Tags: android, dialog, line, statusbar

There show fine line between statusbar and dialog compose when statusbar color change to black for some devices in android. I dont want that white color line.

I tried changing the layout like box to columns but not working, I have created the custom dialog box Layout which background color is also black.
[Dialog with status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNdoI.png)